# meteor on armv6l (raspberry pi)

Tags: javascript, node.js, arm, meteor, raspberry-pi

I like the look of meteor, never tried it before, thought it would make a great platform for a web dashboard on my raspberry pi. Tried the recommended installer and got this:

```
$ curl install.meteor.com | /bin/sh
Unable to install Meteor on unsupported architecture: armv6l
Installation failed.
```

Well, I'm not gonna take that lying down! Am going to try and manually install it, but has anyone tried/failed/succeeded already? Any tips?

Comment: What have you tried? You'll eventually bump into other's progress, or be the first to get it working.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can find a fork of meteor at github called [Meteor universal fork](https://github.com/4commerce-technologies-AG/meteor). That has a ready to go installer for yet unsupported architectures like ARM and BSD.

For the installation just run:

```
cd $HOME

git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/4commerce-technologies-AG/meteor.git
```

and then get the binaries and finish the installation by:

```
$HOME/meteor/meteor --version
```

> Running the above command for the first time will try to download a compatible pre-built dev_bundle and finish the installation. Depending on your hardware this may take some time.

Comment: This answer would be upvoted if you included instructions in this answer how to get started with using it to solve the OP's problem and show the exact steps to take to solve the OP's problem.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker thanks for comment, I hope that the edited answer fits you proposal.

Answer (score 6):

Apparently, there are prebuilt packages for raspi now. Alas, I lost interest long ago - details of prebuilt packages here: http://meteor-universal.tumblr.com/

(Thanks to @Archonic - see the comments below - and if you'd like to make that a real answer, I'd be happy to change the accepted answer for this question.)

I'll keep the text below for reference.

---

(Updating as I go along...)

Note: i'm doing this on the stock debian image, albeit after having installed ruby, passenger and padrino (and all their dependencies). Archlinux may be easier, I don't know.

1. Install node.js

   Does not work by default, followed [instructions here](http://blog.tomg.co/post/21322413373/how-to-install-node-js-on-your-raspberry-pi)
2. Checkout meteor

   ```
   git clone git://github.com/meteor/meteor.git
   ```
3. modify admin/generate-dev-bundle.sh

   Essentially, remove all the instructions regarding building node.js, and all references to a tempdir, so you end up just installing node packages. I will post mine as a gist once it's all figured out...

   Then, run it in an empty folder
4. install mongodb. From source.

   cd to extracted directory, and install using scons

   ```
   sudo apt-get install scons libboost-all-dev
   scons libboost-dev libpcre++-dev xulrunner-1.9.1-dev
   ```

(Note: I will be finishing this soon. I think the trick might be to use meteor's bundle functionality - especially the big red box http://docs.meteor.com/#deploying - but unfortunately my pi has crashed and I'm away from home. Please post if you found that worked, and I'll update this answer accordingly or accept your answer)

Comment: There's pre built binaries now. Installation is pretty easy and takes about 1.5 hours on an old RPi and 30 mins on a new one. http://meteor-universal.tumblr.com