# Run meteor on Raspberry pi (ARM6)

Tags: node.js, meteor

I tried to install meteorJS on my raspberry pi  and I get this error during the installation :

```
"Unable to install on unsupported architecture Meteor: armv6l
 Installation failed. ".
```

There is a solution by modifying the file "admin/generate-dev-bundle.sh" on the meteor core to regenerate the bundle, but what should we put in this file?

Do you have another solution?

Thank you

Comment: You need to rebuild node from source on your raspberry - https://gist.github.com/stolsma/3301813, Be warned it does take a fair amount of time, then just run `npm install meteor` hopefully it should pull through

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10936675/meteor-on-armv6l-raspberry-pi

Comment: @Akshat Thanks but i want the content of the "admin/generate-dev-bundle.sh" file !

Comment: @Baltox could you please change the accepted answer because the fork from IG is outdated and still some old 0.x version of meteor. Thanks, Tom

Answer (score 11, accepted):

FYI, I've put together a fork of meteor that supports the Raspberry Pi, along with full installation instructions. You can find it here: https://github.com/IGx89/meteor

Comment: Thanks! Thank you for keeping this SO Question current :)

Comment: @IGgx86 I'm currently running your fork of meteor and have successfully compiled mongodb on the pi (took forever!). Any chance you could update to meteor 1.x?

Answer (score 5):

I created some update to meteor dev bundler so that you can generate runtimes for yet unsupported architectures. [Update] I will support the meteor realease tags in future as long as they will supprt ARM by themself. Checkout branches on my GitHub repo [Update]. [Update2] Added infos from tumblr site[Update2]

https://github.com/4commerce-technologies-AG/meteor

http://meteor-universal.tumblr.com/

Comment: Tom also made a great install script for 1.0 here https://github.com/4commerce-technologies-AG/meteor

Comment: I created a small internet tumblr site around meteor on ARM. There are many hints about how to install meteor and nodejs on UDOO, Rasberry Pi, Beaglebone and others. Have a look at: http://meteor-universal.tumblr.com/

Answer (score 2):

Quote by [Nick Martin](https://github.com/n1mmy) in verbatim from [Issue #442 in the Meteor github repository](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/442):

```
No immediate plans to add official ARM support. In theory, all the dependencies 
should build on ARM, so you could try building the dev bundle on your platform. 
See https://github.com/meteor/meteor#slow-start-for-developers
```

All required files to build this (yes, even `admin/generate-dev-bundle.sh`) is available in the repository above. Akshat references another SO question that does mention *how* to modify it. Quoting this in verbatim:

`Essentially, remove all the instructions regarding building node.js, and all references to a tempdir, so you end up just installing node packages. I will post mine as a gist once it's all figured out...`

Just give it a spin. It's even possible you can arrive to a solution faster. You never know until you *try*.